# Can't make executable file from eel app in python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, auto-py-to-exe, eel

When I try to create an executable with auto_py_to_exe it builds fine, but when I run it it throws an error:

```
 Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
 File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
 File "eel\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
 File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
 File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

The 'command' auto_py_to_exe runs is:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "web folder path"  "main.py path"
```

Project folder looks like this:
main.py
web
|-main.html
|-main.css
|-main.js
The files are following:

**main.py**

```
import eel

eel.init('./web')
eel.start('./main.html')
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="text">Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
.text {
  color: white;
}
```

**main.js**

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000'
```

I also tried to run just the command as following, still the same error:

```
python -m PyInstaller --onedir --windowed --add-data "C:\Users\fused\Desktop\test\web:web" "C:\Users\fused\Desktop\test\main.py"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because you are using `--windowed` option flag.  When you use the `--windowed` or `--noconsole` you are telling pyinstaller not to run your program with a console attached to it so pyinstaller sets `stderr` and `stdout` to `None`.  One of the libraries you are using is likely writing to `sys.stdout` for logging.

The solution is to put somewhere close to your program's entry point you need to explicitly assign `stderr` and `stdout` to an object that has the a `write` method.  This can be an actual file that you open if you want to store the output of your program into a file, otherwise you can simply use an buffer from the `io` module.

for example to use an actual file:

```
import sys
logfile = open('program_output.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = logfile
sys.stderr = logfile
```

Or if you just wanted to use a buffer:

```
import sys
import io
logfile = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = logfile
sys.stderr = logfile
```